# How to store many images on a webserver?

Tags: mysql, filesystems, storage

I plan to store many images (>100,000) on a webserver.

the filename will be for ex.

> 324-2012-07-25-143544.jpg

the filename is build like this:

> userid-year-month-day-HHMMSS.jpg

this filename will be saved in a mysqldatabase and will be read and from the filename you know the filepath ->

> images/userid/year/month/day/userid-year-month-day-HHMMSS.jpg

so in this example it would be

> images/324/2012/07/25/324-2012-07-25-143544.jpg

any performance problems that can occur when everythin is saved in the basefolder /images?

thank you!

Comment: If you want to use the date parts as the directory structure then make sure you store them uniquely in the database - Iif it will _only_ be used for absolute file access, this is fine. If they're potentially going to be usable in a programmatic way (listing valid years with image) then store them as separate fields. There's nothing worse than trying to split one Dd field into multiple to do processing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sharding files, like you're doing, is a great way to avoid performance problems with having many files in one directory: in this method, you're ensuring that only a few entries (directories or files) are in any given directory. It's also easy to split across multiple volumes if you need to - you simply mount some of the high-level directories in different places.

You should consider a couple things though.

### Identity

If you're going for basically permanent storage of these images, you may want to shard based on id. This is a bit easier to deal with from the DB side (for the same reasons we use an arbitrary primary key in DB design).

Like @Veger suggests: imageid `123456` becomes `/12/1234/123456.jpg`.

#### Security

Using dates, user ids or an auto-increment number may pose a security risk, though, in that they are relatively easy to guess and thus it's pretty easy for someone to harvest all images.

Additionally, having the date in the URL potentially leaks information, if there is no reason for a user to know the upload date.

If you're using a very hard-to-guess key, it provides some level of security against both harvesting and information leakage. For example, you could use a GUID: Image ID `6f33395e-eda8-4486-8b8e-51ea0f91751b` gets stored as `/6/6f33/6f33395e/6f33395e-eda8-4486-8b8e-51ea0f91751b.jpg`.

There are a crazy high number of GUIDs (it's 128bits) and so it would likely take millions of years for someone to harvest everything (even if you don't take any extra steps like limiting connections per IP per hour etc).

#### Volatile images

If your images are volatile -- that is, they expire after some amount of time -- then it may actually be best to shard based on a date structure, eg `/2012/12/14/2012-12-14-hhmmss-userid.jpg`, or you can combine this with a guid and get `/2012/12/14/6f/6f33395e-eda8-4486-8b8e-51ea0f91751b.jpg`.

If you want to delete all of 2011's files, you just `rm -rf 2011`.  A great example of when you'd use this is for log files.

You have to keep in mind that this only really makes sense for a *very* high number of images, because you can do a query in your database to find outdated images based on date, then just delete them one-by-one.

### Granularity of shards

Use higher granularity of shards for the more images you plan to eventually store, but keep in mind that if you go too granular, you are going to lose a lot of overhead disk space to directory entries.

The goal is to keep the number of entries per directory to something the filesystem can handle; good rule of thumb seems to be about 10,000 max. You have to predict the traffic your site will get for the next while. Don't go crazy though, thinking at some point that you maybe will have millions of users a day. It's not impossible to re-shard, but it's a pain. Predict your growth for the next couple years and handle that. If you grow faster and have to re-shard as a result, well, it's a nice problem to be solving. If you run out of disk space because your directory entries take up more room than your images, well, that's a stupid problem to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

- Just use a unique id for each image you store (just a number, like table id field)
- Check what the maximum number of files in a directory on your webserver is
- divide the id by this number to get a directory name
- store the image (with the number) in this directory

For example image number `1` is stored as `/0/1.jpg` and image number `1234567` is stored as `/123/1234567.jpg` (asumming you can store 10000 files in a directory).

Most easy, least amount of noise and optimizes the number of files in a directory (instead of wasting lots of half full directories).

If you *really* are going to store a *lot* of images, use 2 sub-directories! Like, `/0/0/1.jpg` and `/1/12345/123456789.jpg`